# Average time in hours,minutes and seconds in php

Tags: php, average

I have some total sums of hours and need to calculate the average. For example, my total hour value is 2452:43:44 (H:m:s) and the total count is 15. I would like to get the average time in  the same format, that is hours:minutes:seconds. How can we do it in PHP ?

Comment: You probably meant `h:i:s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function average_time($total, $count, $rounding = 0) {
    $total = explode(":", strval($total));
    if (count($total) !== 3) return false;
    $sum = $total[0]*60*60 + $total[1]*60 + $total[2];
    $average = $sum/(float)$count;
    $hours = floor($average/3600);
    $minutes = floor(fmod($average,3600)/60);
    $seconds = number_format(fmod(fmod($average,3600),60),(int)$rounding);
    return $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
}
echo average_time("2452:43:44", 15); // prints "163:30:55"
echo average_time("2452:43:44", 15, 2); // prints "163:30:54.93"
```

Comment: how to calculate ("163:30:54" * 15) then it must be equal to "2452:43:44" just for check?

Comment: @Akam I have a calculator capable of time/angle calculations: `2452:43:44 / 15 = 163:30:54.93`. The calculation is correct though there is some minor rounding error.

Comment: Can you explain what the `$count` variable is for?

Comment: @rar If you take a look at the question, it is about calculating an average from total time. It's like dividing a number with another one, just that the initial value and the result is expressed in `h:i:s` format. `$count` here is the divisor, which is the second number in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Close to [Antony's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493698/antony) solution, but with array of `hours` given:

```
$time = array (
            '2452:43:44',
            '452:43:44',
            '242:43:44',
            '252:43:44',
            '2:43:44'
        );

$seconds = 0;
foreach($time as $hours) {
    $exp = explode(':', strval($hours));
    $seconds += $exp[0]*60*60 + $exp[1]*60 + $exp[2];
}

$average = $seconds/sizeof( $time );
echo floor($average/3600).':'.floor(($average%3600)/60).':'.($average%3600)%60;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$totalhourandmunite+=str_replace(":",'',$date);
strtoheur(round($totalhourandmunite/$nbdate,0));
function strtoheur($temp)
{
    if(strlen($temp)==1) return $temp;
    if(strlen($temp)==2)
        $temp=$temp."00";
    if(strlen($temp)==3)
        $temp="0".$temp;
    $temp=str_split($temp);
    $heure=$temp["0"].$temp["1"];
    $min=$temp["2"].$temp["3"];
    if($min/60>1)
    {
        $min=$min%60;
        $heure++;
    }
    if($min<10 && strlen($min)==1)
        $min="0".$min;
    if($heure>23)
    {
        $heure=$heure%24;
    }
    $temp=$heure.":".$min;
    return $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way would be to change the total hour value in seconds.
2. Divide it by total count value. What you will get is average in seconds.
3. Convert average back in H:m:s format.

Comment: You probably meant `h:i:s`.

Comment: @DainisAbols: Thanks for your observation, but Alwin has specified H:m:s in his question so i mentioned it that way. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @BhavikShah Thanks man...I opted for the first one. anyway thanks for the answer. Also thanks