# DateTime::add adds hours even when interval should only be seconds

Tags: php, datetime

This comes from my previous question on getting the average time interval over a specified data set, [located here][1]. I'll post the entire function again:

```
function getATBData($siteID, $fromDate, $toDate)
{
    global $pdo;

    $ATBarray = array();
    $maxATB;
    $minATB;
    $avgATB;
    $totalATB=new DateTime("@0");
    $totalEvents=0;
    $timetable;

    $query = "SELECT id, siteID, start_time, end_time FROM atb_log WHERE siteID=:siteID AND (start_time BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate) AND (end_time BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":siteID", $siteID);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fromDate", $fromDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(":toDate", $toDate);
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        $timeDiff = date_diff(new DateTime($row['start_time']),new DateTime($row['end_time']), true); //force absolute
        if(!isset($maxATB) OR dateIntervalInSeconds($timeDiff) > dateIntervalInSeconds($maxATB))
            $maxATB = $timeDiff;
        if(!isset($minATB) OR dateIntervalInSeconds($timeDiff) < dateIntervalInSeconds($minATB))
            $minATB = $timeDiff;
        $totalATB->add($timeDiff);
        echo "added " . $timeDiff->format("%H:%I:%S") . " total is now: " . $totalATB->format("H:i:s") . "<br />";
        $totalEvents++;
    }

    if($totalEvents!=0)
    {
        $avgATB = average_time($totalATB->format("H:i:s"),$totalEvents,0);
    }
    else
    {
        $avgATB=0;
        $maxATB=new DateInterval('PT0S');
        $minATB=new DateInterval('PT0S');
    }
    //$avgSeconds = new DateInterval("PT" . $avgATB . "S");
    $ATBarray['max'] = $maxATB->format("%H:%I:%S");
    $ATBarray['min'] = $minATB->format("%H:%I:%S");
    $ATBarray['avg'] = $avgATB;
    $ATBarray['total'] = $totalATB->format("H:i:s");
    $ATBarray['events'] = $totalEvents;

    return $ATBarray;

}
```

Given this function, I have added an output statement to try to debug why I was getting such a large time interval for my total time (when most of the values are a small number of seconds) and this is what it's outputting:

```
added 00:00:02 total is now: 01:00:02
added 00:00:00 total is now: 02:00:02
added 00:00:01 total is now: 03:00:03
added 00:00:01 total is now: 04:00:04
added 00:00:00 total is now: 05:00:04
added 00:00:02 total is now: 06:00:06
added 00:00:00 total is now: 07:00:06
```

and so on. So it seems like, despite the time to be added only being a couple seconds, it adds an hour every time. The call to `add()` on `$timeDiff` above is how I'm adding.

So the question is - is there a different way to call the `add()` function such that it will only add the seconds? Am I calling it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, average difference in seconds, why that PHP swath of code if your database can give it to you:

```
SELECT 
  SEC_TO_TIME(MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) AS max_timediff,
  SEC_TO_TIME(MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) AS min_timediff,
  SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) AS avg_timediff,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) AS sum_timediff,
  COUNT(id) as total_events
FROM atb_log 
WHERE 
  siteID=:siteID 
  AND start_time > :fromDate
  AND end_time < :toDate
```

Format those min/max/avg/sum of seconds as you like.

Comment: Call it more familiarity with PHP than SQL? :) This is great, I might rewrite these functions to do this instead.
Those results can be formatted from PHP, or would you do this from SQL as well?

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME` should do it, I'll add it in.

Comment: This saved me a ton of work. Thank you very much. The lesson learned today is to let the database do the work for you if possible, mainly for `DateTime` work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the answer to your other question, this is a DST (Daylight Savings Time) problem. In the U.S., DST has already begun; in Europe not.

Try this code:

```
timecheck("Europe/Amsterdam");
timecheck("America/Los_Angeles");

function timecheck($timezone) {
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

$totalATB=new DateTime("@0");
$t1 = "2014-01-01 17:30:00";
$t2 = "2014-01-01 17:35:00";

$dt1 = new DateTime($t1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($t2);

$timeDiff = date_diff($dt1, $dt2, true);

printf("[%s] Starting with with: %s\n", $timezone, $totalATB->format("H:i:s"));
$totalATB->add($timeDiff);
printf("[%s] added %s, total is now: %s\n", $timezone, $timeDiff->format("%H:%I:%S"), $totalATB->format("H:i:s"));
}
```

The output:

```
[Europe/Amsterdam] Starting with with: 00:00:00
[Europe/Amsterdam] added 00:05:00, total is now: 00:05:00
[America/Los_Angeles] Starting with with: 00:00:00
[America/Los_Angeles] added 00:05:00, total is now: 01:05:00
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to go back to your answer on that question. So I'm a bit confused - how can adding an interval like this be affected by DST? More importantly, how can I prevent that from ever happening? It's crucial that DST never affect this sort of thing as it completely changes the accuracy of the data (throwing off not only the total, but the average as well).

Comment: Don't want to blur things, but the above code didn't reproduce the issue here (no 1h is added).

Comment: I actually just found this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61955   One user reports setting a certain timezone does fix the issue, but...won't it be messed up again when DST hits Europe?

Comment: FYI @Niloct I ran the code and it did reproduce the results described above. Not sure what it suggests that it didn't for you, though.

Comment: @rar great! If it ain't broke... =)

Comment: So if I originally define my total DateTime object as `new DateTime("@0",new DateTimeZone("UTC"));`, will this ignore all DST details? It seems to be so far.

Comment: Call me old fashioned, but I'm used to handling time values and intervals as integers (seconds). Much simpler for basic calculations such as average or ETA. I haven't enough experience to give you a competent answer here, I suggest to play around with the DateInterval and DateTime classes a bit and try to examine their native value (seconds).

Comment: Leaving this as simple as possible as far as `DateTime` goes may be old-fashioned, but it seems the most sensible to me. I've accepted @Wrikken's answer for this reason. It's all handled at the database side, and it saves me a ton of PHP code.