# Total Duration using DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I've asked a few questions today based on some problems I've been having involving average and total duration of time between several DateTime values. In counting this duration, it was previously recommended that I use a DateTime object define as follows to store the total duration:

```
$totalTime = new DateTime("@0");
```

The question I have is - is it actually best to count total duration this way? Will it work to count the total duration of several events?

EDIT: The times being added are durations calculated by `date_diff()`, so they are `DateInterval` objects (which can easily be added to `DateTime` objects).

Comment: I took the liberty of [answering that other question with just a pure SQL solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22390868/358679), it seems far more apt then swaths of PHP code which IMHO isn't needed.

Comment: So ultimately, the better way to go would be to sum up the times in SQL and not bother with storing the sums in PHP? (as an answer to this question)

Comment: Well, this isn't an answer to your current question, it's an answer to the actual problem you're trying to solve. But it is the route I'd take. In my opinion `DateTIme` objects aren't terribly good at just time differences: date problems you don't want, DST problems, going over midnight, all for just an average time. If you'd like an answer to your current question: I'd just calculate it with the seconds like integers, and format it with some math (`$hours=floor($seconds/3600); $seconds = $seconds % 3600; $minutes = floor($seconds/60); $seconds = $seconds % 60; echo "$hour:$minutes:$seconds";`

Comment: I can say that your 2nd example (`new DateTime("@0",new DateTimeZone("UTC"));`) is total nonsense, because if you apply timestamp as first parameter, which is already in UTC!, your 2nd paramater is ignored. [Please read **note** on 2nd parameter `$timestamp` on php manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: That's a very good point. I even knew that, so I'm not sure why I wasn't thinking about it here. I've removed it from my question.

Comment: @Wrikken what is the best way to sum up my time in only seconds and then convert back? Unfortunately with your SQL answer in my other question, I get a total of -72 hours or so.

Comment: Ignore my nonsense. The issue was that I was using your query without considering the additional `WHERE` clauses that I needed for my data. Far too many bad mistakes on my part in this project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to gather so far, there seem to be 2 "better" methods of doing this sort of thing.

1. While still using a `DateTime` object, add all of the times up as seconds. This allows for simple integer addition/subtraction/whatever for counting the data, avoiding potential DateTime bugs/weird behaviour. In the end, just convert your seconds into a `DateTime` format for output.
2. If pulling from a database (as I am), simply use SQL's available features for `SUM`, `TIME_DIFF`, and so on, to calculate directly from the database. From there, you pull it into a `DateTime` object in PHP and, without having to modify that object at all, output your results. This solved my own problem of going over 23 hours (which would go back to midnight if adding to a `DateTime` object in PHP).

I'm definitely open to other suggestions, however.